# Missing Image when using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the paperclip gem to display images but the output i get it missing image

Below is the controller and model files respectively

Controlfile

```
class HandymenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_handyman, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
      if params[:profession].blank?
          @handymen = Handyman.all.order("created_at DESC")
      else
          @profession_id = Profession.find_by(name: params[:profession]).id
          @handymen = Handyman.where(:profession_id => @profession_id).order("created_at DESC")
      end 
  end

  def show
  end 

  def new
      @handyman = current_user.handymen.build
      @professions = Profession.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }
  end

  def create
      @handyman = current_user.handymen.build(handyman_params)
      @handyman.profession_id = params[:profession_id]

      if @handyman.save
          redirect_to root_path
      else
          render 'new'
      end
  end 

  def edit
      @professions = Profession.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }
  end

  def update
      @handyman.profession_id = params[:profession_id]
      if @handyman.update(handyman_params)
          redirect_to handyman_path(@handyman)
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
  end

  def destroy
      @handyman.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def handyman_params
      params.require(:handyman).permit(:name, :location, :phone_number, :profession_id, :handyman_img)
  end 

  def find_handyman
      @handyman = Handyman.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Model File

```
class Handyman < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession

  has_attached_file :handyman_img, styles: { handyman_index: "250x350>", handyman_show: "325x475>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :handyman_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Error Log

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/handyman_imgs/handyman_show/missing.png"):   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in`block in
>   call'   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in
>   `catch'   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`
>   call'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'   railties
>   (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'   activesupport
>   (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in
>   `call'   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'   railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:165:in`call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
>
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
>
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`block in
>   start_thread'
>
> Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (4.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (120.1ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (3.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (409.4ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb
>   (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb
>   within layouts/javascript (288.3ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb
>   within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)   Rendered
>   C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
>   (431.4ms)

Comment: how do you display the image in your view? where's the error log? ....

Comment: just a second please

Comment: here is the show.html.erb file

Answer (score 0):

In your erb view you should have something like

```
<%= image_tag(@handyman.handyman_img(:handyman_index)) %>
<%= image_tag(@handyman.handyman_img(:handyman_show)) %>
```

depending on what size you want to show.

Comment: which erb file are you talking about?

Comment: He means the view file where you want to display the image.

Comment: i did it in the show.html.erb file and it didnt change it